# iPad: Two Table Views one Controller

Tags: xcode, ipad, tableview

In my iPad App I am using a SplitView. In Portrait mode, instead of using the popOver, I have another Table View that´s connected to the same controller that has the info for the View that appears in Landscape.

My App works great, but I have an 1 warning when I Build:
The "view" outlet of "App List View Controller" is connected to "Table View" but "App List View Controller" already has a "Table View" child fulfilling this role.

I would like to know if doing this will bring some trouble that I have not detected? Or if My App could be rejected because of this?

Comment: App is already in iTunes and running fine.